# Getting info fails on first click; succeeds on second click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm getting info from an api to feed a list with the next code:

```
function listData (){
       $http.get('http://cupones.clickonero.com.mx/api/InvoicePayments?')
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.list = data.data.Response;
             });
           }
```

and on the html view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="info in list | filter: search">
                <th>{{info.Id}}</th>
                <th><a data-toggle="modal" href="#detailInvoice" ng-click="gralInfo(info)">{{info.Name}}</a></th>
                <th>{{info.value}}</th>
                <th>{{info.FiscalFolio}}</th>
</tr>
```

Then, to see the complete datails of every value on the list, i use the next piece of code:

```
$scope.gralInfo = function(h){
        $scope.infoMan = h;
        //console.log($scope.infoMan);
    }
```

Html view:

```
<div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><strong>DETAILS OF REQUEST NUMBER {{infoMan.Id}}</strong></h5>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3"><strong>Name:</strong> {{infoMan.Name}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3"><strong>Invoice:</strong> {{infoMan.InvoiceNumber}}</div>
                        </div>
```

As you can see, with `gralInfo` i can consult on every click the info. Yesterday, i changed another part of my code using ngRoute (but not this parts). And, since then, every time i clicked to see the details, don't return the data on the first click. It does until the second clic.

It sounds akward, and, at this point, i didn't find why is making this. Anyone have any idea why is working like this?

Also, i'm using $rootScope to pass some values from my home to the list. Do you think this is happening because of this?

Comment: maybe that data-toggle="modal"  is blocking your ng-click? try to remove it and move modal opening logic to  ng-click="gralInfo(info, $event)", then prevent triggering a[href]  with    $event.preventDefault() in gralInfo function

Comment: Thanx, it works with the very first click!

Comment: Mixing jQuery click handlers with AngularJS click handlers is asking for problems. Consider using the [$uibModal service](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal), Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team.

Comment: Thanx for the sugestion, i'll use it :)